# Undefined variable (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have this error in my view and cannot find out where is the problem:

**MY Controller name 'Question':**

```
public function show_all_question_set() {
$data = array();
$data['question_set'] = $this->Question_Model->select_all_question_set();
$this->load->view('question/make_set', $data);
}
```

**My Model name 'Question_Model':**

```
public function select_all_question_set() {
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_question_set');
$query_result = $this->db->get();
$result = $query_result->result();
return $result;
}
```

**My view name 'make_set':**

```
<?php
foreach ($question_set as $all_set) {
?>   
<tr>      
<td align="center">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><em class="fa fa-pencil"></em></a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"><em class="fa fa-trash"></em></a>
</td>
<td> <?php echo $all_set->exam_name; ?>  </td>
<td> <?php echo $all_set->subject_name; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $all_set->set_name; ?> </td>
<td align="center">
<a href="#"class="btn btn-default"><em class="fa fa-book"> দেখুন </em></a>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Table : tbl_question_set(set_id, exam_name, subject_name, set_name)

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: question_set

Filename: question/make_set.php

Line Number: 90

Comment: So which is line 90??

Comment: Line 90 is : foreach ($question_set as $all_set) {

Comment: Another work around would be to check `$data` before passing it to the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$this->load->model('Question_Model');
add this line to load the model if model is not autoloaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
i think you are getting error because you write model name in capital letter.. please try this. paste this code in your model hopefully it will work..

public function show_all_question_set() {
$data = array();
$data['question_set'] = $this->question_model->select_all_question_set();
$this->load->view('question/make_set', $data);
}
```

Comment: did you load the model in construct?

Comment: public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('question_model');
       
    }

Comment: what was the problem?